# Issue splitting string with RegEx that includes brackets, semicolons and spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string below:

```
var sphere1 = CSG.sphere({center: [5, 5, 5], radius: 10, resolution: resolution });<br>
var sphere2 = sphere1.translate([12, 5, 0]);<br>
```

That I try to split using the following `(/,| |[|]|;/` as my regex):

```
var words = $(selector).html().split(/,| |[|]|;/);
```

I have three problems:

- I lose the semicolons at the end of the lines (before the BR tag) - they should be independently split in the WORDS array
- The string that includes the first number in the bracket (5 or 12) also includes the open-bracket
- The string that includes the last number in the bracket (5 or 0) also includes the close-bracket.

Basically, I am trying to specifically 'isolate' out any numbers so that I can increment/modify them individually.

Any ideas for the RegEx?

Answer (score 0):

This might give you a starting point

http://jsfiddle.net/JqT4k/1/

```
var str = "var sphere1 = CSG.sphere({center: [5, 5, 5], radius: 10, resolution: resolution }); var sphere2 = sphere1.translate([12, 5, 0]);";

//evaluates each replace individually
function match_eval(m){
    // m is going to be [5, 5, 5] and then [12, 5, 0], you can do with this as you see fit
    return "[0,0,0]";    
}

alert(str.replace(/\[( *\d+ *,?)+\]/g, match_eval));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However I'm really looking to address each individual number (each 0 or each 5 for example), it could also be a number not in a bracket.  For example using /(0-9)+/ correctly matches them but removes the "offending" number matches instead of adding them in the array.

Comment: Well you can modify this so that it only matches on each number and use this same process.  Still, I don't know how you plan to know which numbers are which.

Comment: actually what I do is wrap each array element in a span tag with.its individual ID, and then replace the DIV with a concatenation of the spans:

Comment: Ok yeah I think I see what you're doing.  My solution won't work at all then.

Comment: I think what I'll do when I try a bit later is do a split, then a match, then combine the two into an array using a for loop.

Comment: I've fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jonnycowboy/w4n3W/12/

I used a method I found on another stackoverflow question/answer:

'var nums = $(selector).html().match(/[0-9]+/g);
var words = $(selector).html().split(/[0-9]+/g); 
newHtml += '<span id="p'+ 0 + '">' + words[0] + '</span>'; 
for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    newHtml += '<span id="p'+ (2*i + 1) + '">' + nums[i] + '</span>'; 
    newHtml += '<span id="p'+ (2*i + 2) + '">' + words[i+1] + '</span>';
}'

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jonnycowboy/w4n3W/12 I used a method I found on another stackoverflow question/answer: 'var nums = $(selector).html().match(/[0-9]+/g); var words = $(selector).html().split(/[0-9]+/g); newHtml += '' + words[0] + ''; for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) { newHtml += '' + nums[i] + ''; newHtml += '' + words[i+1] + ''; }' –

Comment: When you post code, select the code and click the button that looks like `{ }`.  This will format your code and make it look all nice.